# facebook c# 5 - FacebookWebClient throws Typeinitializer-exception

Tags: facebook-c#-sdk

my problem is as follows: I have just migrated from using the Facebook C# API 4 -> v. 5.0.50 (as of 2011-07-11), therefore I had to change some lines of code and started using the FacebookWebClient instead of the former FacebookApp. I use this class to navigate the Graph API. I use the functionality inside a WCF service, which receives only the access_token as a parameter, which it passes to the FacebookWebClient.

Everything worked just fine under v.4, however after replacing and re-referencing the dlls the application started throwing the exception "**The type initializer for 'Facebook.FacebookApplication' threw an exception.**"

---

The exception stack trace is:

at Facebook.FacebookClient..ctor(String accessToken) in e:\Prabir\Documents\Projects\facebooksdk\v5.0.50\Source\Facebook\FacebookClient.cs:line 48 at Facebook.Web.FacebookWebClient..ctor(String accessToken) in e:\Prabir\Documents\Projects\facebooksdk\v5.0.50\Source\Facebook.Web\FacebookWebClient.cs:line 36 at Korito.MyKorito.FetchKorito(String token) at Korito.MyKorito.KoritoAPI(String token) at SyncInvokeKoritoAPI(Object , Object[] , Object[] ) at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SyncMethodInvoker.Invoke(Object instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]& outputs) at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc& rpc) at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc& rpc) at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage31(MessageRpc& rpc) at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean isOperationContextSet)

---

I have referenced (only) the following dll-s:

- facebook.dll
- facebook.web.dll
- facebook.web.mvc.dll

the code segment is as follows:

var client = new Facebook.Web.FacebookWebClient("/*auth_token_received_as_a_parameter*/");
dynamic me = client.Get("/me");

I use the .net 4 framework.

Any assistance is much appreciated!
Cheers,
Alois

Answer (score 0):

FacebookWebClient is usually used when you want the SDK to automatically add the access token using the signed request or cookies.

```
var fb = new FacebookWebClient();
```

Since you are getting the access token as parameter. You could just reference Facebook.dll only and use FacebookClient instead.

```
var client = new FacebookClient("access_token");
```

You can continue to use FacebookApp which has been moved to Facebook.Web.dll in v5.x (You might not see it in intellisense as it is hidden but it still works as we tried to maintain as maximum compatibilty with v4. note: but it has been marked as obsolete, this allows users to easily migrate their apps from v4 to v5.)

Comment: thank you prabir for your reply and also congrats for your good work. I have tried both the FacebookWebClient, as well as the FacebookClient, both behave the same. Also the FacebookApp does not work in this scenario any more.

I reproduced the same case in a console application, where at first I imported just your dlls (facebook.dll from net40-client and facebook.web.dll from net40), which did not work. After some research I figured out that I need to include Newtonsoft.Json, which I did and the console app worked now ok. But this did not work for the WCF app. I guess the issue is in the iis?

Comment: which version are you using? starting from 5.0.10 we have removed dependency on Newtonsoft.Json as we use a new lightweight inbuilt json library called http://simplejson.codeplex.com

Comment: I used the version 5.0.50. I could not solve the problem in the WCF, so I went back to the v4. v5 works splendid with console applications I use on the same machine, but for no obvious reason fails when used inside the WCF service.

Comment: could u upload your project somewhere using WCF and post it in codeplex discussion forum. i will have a look at it personally.